# Other people with scar similar to that of Harry's?

Tags: harry-potter

> Never wondered how you got that mark on yer forehead? That was no ordinary cut. That's what yeh get when a Powerful, evil curse touches yeh -- took care of yer mum an' dad an' yer house, even -- but it didn't work on you, an' that's why yer famous, Harry.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone Page 43*</sub>

This is what Hagrid told Harry in the introductional days of Harry in the Wizarding world...

There are many great wizards in history. Many have cast curses. Many curses have touched people. Therefore, there should be many such marks on people's foreheads.

Are there any other examples of this?

<sub>I want canon based answers. I have been told that the HP wiki is false. So, no answers from there please. Any other source is valid...</sub>

Comment: I think Harry was the only one that survived Avada Kedavra, that's why he has that scar. I don't think there is anyone else who survived such a curse.

Comment: The only other in canon curse survivals I can think of are Draco Malfoy when he was hit by SectumSempra I think it mentions scarring at some point, and George Weasley who lost an Ear which certainly did not heal.

Comment: Dumbledore had a metro map shaped scar on his knee, mentioned in *Stone*, and a blight mark on his hand from the Gaunt ring.

Comment: Are you asking if **1.** there are other people with scars caused by the Avada Kedavra, or **2.** people with scars caused by *other* curses or **3.** people with any scars in general?

Comment: @Mooz both 1 and 2, and obviously not 3!

Comment: @Simon Agreed, add it as an answer please. Also, please mention the source of scarring. AFAIK, I don't see and scarring with Draco... maybe I have missed something :P

Comment: @b_jonas certainly, you are right. I missed it. Please add that as an answer.

Comment: **1.** Is fine (good question). **2.** Unless you specify *which* curse, then the question might be liable to be closed due to it being "too broad"; as "list" questions are not *usually* accepted here.

Comment: Also, might be worth considering splitting them into two separate questions (might get you more rep also :p)!

Comment: @Mooz 2. I don't have a list of curses. But, it is obvious that it isn't too broad, because we are talking of curses which **can** leave such scars; are there too many of these? And splitting into _which_ two questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are many great wizards in history. Many have cast curses. Many
>   curses have touched people. Therefore, there should be many such marks
>   on people's foreheads.
>
> Are there any other examples of this?

- Alastor Moody has several scars on his face. I'd imagine that one of them had to be lethal. So much for *constant vigilance*.
- Bill Weasly got bitten in the face (not sure if on the forehead, though). This may not count as a spell cast on him, but coming from a werewolf it is most certainly a lethal curse, with a scar.
- George Weasly lost an ear to Sectumsempra. It had difficulties healing (or it didn't at all). Probably a lethal curse.
- This may be far-fetched, but Voldemort's resurrection was technically a number of spells cast on himself. Albeit still handsome, his face definitely changed.

I always wondered if Voldemort living in Quirrell's head left some sort of scar.

Comment: I wonder if there could be a variation of Umbridge's quill that acts on your face. That'd be so cool.

Comment: I think it's Bill who got bitten, by an untransformed werewolf. George or Fred got his ear shot off (not sure which one). Generally, curses are very difficult or outright impossible to heal.

Comment: @Andreas: Aha, yeah. Thanks, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: It's OK, @Andreas, even Mrs. Weasley can't remember whether it was George or Fred whose ear was shot off...